# Difference between the internal procedures and functions in Progress4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Both internal procedures and functions are accepting the parameters to give the output. So what is the use of using Internal procedures instead of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user-defined function is used when you want to perform some calculation and return a single value. In this respect it is the same as a built-in ABL function, like the SUBSTRING or EXP functions. Putting this calculation code in a FUNCTION block instead of inline in your code allows you to put it in one place and reference it multiple times without code duplication.

An internal procedure is also an encapsulated piece of code that does some work, but it is more general-purpose. While a function must return a single value, an internal procedure may or may not have input parameters or output parameters.

https://docs.progress.com/category/openedge-archives

Comment: Well, oddly enough functions can have OUTPUT parameters too.

Comment: Functions are most appropriate when your typical use case will be to embed the function call into other statements that use the return value. For instance:

s2 = substring( s1, firstSpace( s1 )).

where firstSpace() is a user defined function that returns the offset of the first space character in a string.

Procedures must be RUN - so you cannot embed them in other statements. And if you have more than one return value or output parameter procedures are generally more logical and sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Also functions (like methods) parameters and return value type are checked at compile time, which removes some potential problems at run time later.

Answer (score 0):

The question acknowledges that both functions and internal procedures allow OUTPUT parameters and asks "what is the use" of internal procedures *instead of* functions.

To me, this implies that the poster is contemplating always using functions and deprecating internal procedures and is asking: "what would I lose if I do that?"

Two things spring to mind:

1. Sort of the opposite of Jean-Christophe Cardot's point: you would lose some automatic type conversions and syntactic flexibility about the parameter lists.  Some people see that flexibility in a negative light.  Others see it as a positive.
2. You need to "forward declare" your functions or use dynamic invocations.  With an internal procedure you can RUN it without providing a declaration earlier in the code.

If you tend to think that strict type checking is useful then these are probably not benefits that you think of as being lost.  If you prefer more flexible behaviors, then you may regret choosing functions rather than internal procedures.

Comment: You will also loose the option to return an error when only using functions. (At least with the classic error handling, I'm not sure about the more modern throw/catch exception handling.)